# robot_localization tf transform jitters when stopping motion

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

We're trying to use `r_l` on an outdoor ground vehicle with an IMU affixed to the top, and two RTK GPS receivers fore and aft. The IMU provides roll and pitch at 10 Hz (as `imu0`), and the GPS provides relative position (meters from base station) and yaw, and optionally pitch, at 10 Hz (as `pose0`). We don't have any wheel encoders, so we don't have a typical odometry source. As a result, we simply use a static transform from `map` to `odom`, and we are using `r_l` to generate a transform from `odom` to `base_link`.

`r_l` seems to provide a very accurate transform most of the time (judged by visual inspection of rviz), but when the vehicle stops the estimated position of `base_link` jitters (or oscillates) for 1-2 seconds by 0.1-0.5 meters primarily along the vehicle's X axis, then stops at the correct position. However, if we remove `imu0` as an input into `r_l`, the transform stops smoothly and quickly (as does the physical vehicle).

This jitter occurs even when the following are true:

- The IMU and GPS do not provide competing measurements for the same axes of motion (i.e., we remove pitch from the GPS input)
- The covariance matrix diagonal on the IMU is temporarily set to `1e12` (for debug purposes), which we would imagine would cause the `r_l` filters to more or less ignore the IMU input
- The IMU data are all temporarily set to `0` (for debug purposes), and only an irrelevant axis (e.g., `Z''`) is configured to be active

An example GPS message and IMU message are below, as is the YAML configuration for `r_l`.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated! Thank you!

`imu0`:

```
---
header: 
  seq: 4
  stamp: 
    secs: 1487210998
    nsecs: 225980997
  frame_id: base_link
orientation: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
  w: 1.0
orientation_covariance: [1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000000000.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular_velocity_covariance: [1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000000000.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
linear_acceleration_covariance: [1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000000000.0]
---
```

`pose0`:

```
---
header: 
  seq: 2395
  stamp: 
    secs: 1487211196
    nsecs: 500669002
  frame_id: odom
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -3.85235159044
      y: -5.17830684957
      z: 0.00309827089337
    orientation: 
      x: 0.00792342224031
      y: -0.0124397107908
      z: 0.53716653655
      w: 0.843347250536
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-12, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
---
```

`r_l` YAML configuration:

```
robot_localization:
  map_frame: /map
  odom_frame: /odom
  base_link_frame: /base_link
  world_frame: /odom

  frequency: 25
  sensor_timeout: 0.11

  pose0: /gps_receiver/base_link
  pose0_config: [True, True, True,
                 False, False, True,
                 False, False, False,
                 False, False, False,
                 False, False, False]

  imu0: /effector/imu/cab
  imu0_config: [False, False, False,
                False, False, False,
                False, False, False,
                False, False, False,
                False, False, True]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254784/robot_localization-tf-transform-jitters-when-stopping-motion/) by [roboticist17](https://answers.ros.org/users/29371/roboticist17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-02-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-02-21**:
Both of your GPS sensors output in the `odom` frame, correct? How are you accounting for their offsets from the vehicle center?

**Comment by [roboticist17](https://answers.ros.org/users/29371/roboticist17/) on 2017-02-21**:
Thanks Tom! I'm actually just computing an average of their values, weighted to account for the aft receiver being slightly closer to center. I'm then outputting that as a `PoseWithCovarianceStamped` in the `odom` frame and using it with `r_l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I'd have to see a bag file and full configuration. Re: this point

> The IMU data are all temporarily set
> to 0 (for debug purposes), and only an
> irrelevant axis (e.g., Z'') is
> configured to be active

How is your IMU mounted, and what is the `base_link`->`imu` transform? I am also very suspicious of the fact that your IMU Z acceleration has (a) a value of 0 and (b) a massive covariance in the sample message. Covariance values can have subtle effects, even in other axes.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roboticist17](https://answers.ros.org/users/29371/roboticist17/) on 2017-03-02**:
OK, since we have good pose via RTK GPS I may try to hack something together on my own for now, then follow up if it seems like an EKF is necessary. Re IMU accel and covariance, those were just testing values--same issue with normal/correct values. I was just trying to isolate the issue. Thanks!